# Why is there such a big difference with these JPG file sizes?

Tags: jpeg, color-spaces, file-size

I have 2 nearly identical JPG images that have been processed externally, but one file is much larger (in file size) than the other.
I have been looking at all the metadata and embedded information but still do not know why they are different.

First file 1.46MB - https://www.dropbox.com/s/98cn46ojbqlu51q/1-1-marriott-international-inc-wounded-warriors-temp-afab192d-5424-4806-b2e6-ba3362cafb8a.jpg

Second file - 5.63MB - https://www.dropbox.com/s/42b2qzunwp79fpg/1-1-marriottmemorialday2014-142id-e98d4a3c1a4e-temp-0fbf7661-66b6-4589-944a-c67d9d8a1f89.jpg2700x2700.jpg

The only difference I can see is that the larger file has no colour profile embedded, and I believe the original of it was Adobe RGB color space. The first/smaller file is sRGB
but I don't see how it could make a 4MB size difference.

EDIT: I also noticed smaller file has 583,372 colours and the larger file has 705,988 colours.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference I see is that they're saved with different JPEG quality parameters - the smaller file has quality 91 (according to GIMP), whereas the larger file has quality 99. File size can grow pretty exponentially at high quality parameters.

Resaving the larger file at quality 91 reduces it to around 2.2 Mb, which while still significantly bigger than the smaller file is at least in the same ballpark.

Comment: It does look like this is the biggest factor. I didn't realize you could see what quality the jpg was saved at previously so thanks for that tip!